# Do opposite charges feel a force when allowed to freely move?

Tags: gravity, electric-fields

A freely falling body in a gravitational field does not feel any force. Does the same thing apply for electric attraction?
That is, consider a light body with a large positive charge and an electron accelerating towards it due to electric attraction. Will the election feel any force?
We are assuming that gravity can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I would define "feeling a force" as *measuring an internal force*. There is nothing internal to a point object. Electrons appear to be point-like, so they have no internal forces.

A charged object with spatial extent can measure an internal force. For a toy model thought experiment, consider two non-rotating charged point objects with charges $Q_1$, $Q_2$, masses $m_1$, $m_2$, connected at equilibrium by a massless, neutral, ideal spring. Expose them to a constant electric field aligned with the displacement between them and compute the amount by which the spring stretches or compresses as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The observation that objects cannot "feel" uniform gravitational fields is essentially the observation that "gravitational mass" (the $m$ in the gravitational force law) is identical to (or at least proportional to) "inertial mass" (the $m$ in Newton's second law). When you think of it this way, it becomes clear that a charged object in a uniform electric field *will* generally "feel" the electric field, because charge is generally *not* uniformly distributed across mass.

In particular, for normal matter, electrons carry ~1000x as much charge for their mass than the protons do. So uniform electric fields should definitely be "felt." And this agrees with what we see: a strong electric field will tend to do violence to normal matter (e.g. cause sparks), even if the field is completely uniform! At weaker fields, we also make practical use of this behavior, such as in speakers, which may contain a crystal that changes shape under an applied field (even if that field is uniform). Analogous effects are not possible with gravity, since objects do not change shape or catch fire under uniform gravitational fields.

To explain a bit more: When we speak of an object "feeling" acceleration, what we really mean is that different parts of the object are accelerating at different rates. The tendency of the distances between the parts to change is what is detected and interpreted as acceleration. (There are some subtleties to this definition.)

In the case of a gravitational force, any piece of a body of volume $dV$ feels force $\mathbf F=\rho_g\mathbf g\,dV,$ where $\rho_g$ is the density of gravitational mass ("gravitational charge") and $\mathbf g$ is the gravitational field. Then the piece accelerates at $\mathbf a=\mathbf F/(\rho_i dV)=\mathbf g(\rho_g/\rho_i),$ where $\rho_i$ is the density of interial mass. $\mathbf a$ being constant, given that $\mathbf g$ is constant, implies $\rho_g/\rho_i$ is constant. The gravitational mass, the "whatever it is" of an object that causes it to gravitate, has a fixed relation to the inertial mass, the "whatever it is" of an object that causes it to move in response to force.

If we swap out $\rho_g$ for $\rho_q,$ the density of electric charge, and swap out $\mathbf g$ for $\mathbf E,$ the electric field, then we have reason to believe that $\rho_q/\rho_i$ is not constant (we observe that charge is *not* proportional to mass), so we have reason to disbelieve that constant $\mathbf E$ causes constant $\mathbf a$ across a general body. We instead expect uniform electric fields to (try to) "tear apart" objects, in general.